# Does this OED citation of "third-rate," and the origin of the idiomatic term, relate to the British Royal Navy?

Tags: etymology

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-rate), [this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117967/first-rate-second-rate-and-third-rate), and [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/third), **third-rate** derives from a term related to ships, particularly a rating system in the British Royal Navy.

However, etymonline dates the term to **1814**, while this site cites Wikipedia, and Wikipedia attributes the term first to "the **1720s**," but later describes the rating system as originating in **1620**.

But the earliest actual citation I can find is in the *OED*, which gives no explanation of the contextual development of the phrase, but provides a date earlier than etymonline with a context to which I am unsure the British Royal Navy relates, because the publication is about housing and land.

> **third rate**  *n.*
>
> **1656**   H. Phillippes *Purchasers Pattern* (1676) A iv b   An house of the **third rate.**

This citation is all that is given for the compound "third-rate" in the online edition of the *OED*, there is no definition provided or additional notes.

Does the *OED*'s declination to attribute the term to shipping in combination with a lack of citations related to shipping that antedate the citation related to housing and land indicate that the direct connection to the British Royal Navy is dubious?

Is there evidence that "third-rate" referred to ships before it referred to houses, as Wikipedia claims without in-line citations, while providing no cited texts using the term?  Or are there other reputable sources that establish the validity of the British Royal Navy connection -- particularly sources that might help explain the *OED*'s lonely attestation?

Comment: WP entries need not always be backed by citations. OED does a meticulous search.

Comment: What are "nautical ships"?

Comment: @Kris I suppose I meant as opposed to spaceships. :)  Or any other thing that could be termed a "ship."  I have a tendency to be specific when I'm unsure if I'm being clear.  Title edited.

Comment: If this is true :*In 1626, a table drawn up by Charles I used the term rates for the first time in a classification scheme connected with the Navy. The table specified the amount of monthly wages a seaman or officer would earn, in an ordered scheme of six rates, from "first-rate" to "sixth-rate"* https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rating_system_of_the_Royal_Navy - it appears that OED citation is an early, idiomatic  one,  outside the shipping system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First-rate, second-rate, and third-rate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117967/first-rate-second-rate-and-third-rate)

Comment: This sounds like a tax rate reference. For instance, the window tax had three levels - < 10 windows, 10 - 20 windows, and >20 windows. It could just be a way of saying the house had less than 10 windows. (note, just an example, the window tax was a bit later on.)

Comment: Especially considering the supposed nautical origin, it's not at all unlikely that the terminology originated with prostitutes:  First-rate prostitutes, second-rate prostitutes,  and third-rate prostitutes, your choice depending on which you can afford.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by [Steve B](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/309222/steve-b) in [another answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/456687/129681), [*OED*](http://oed.com/) attests the derivation of 'third-rate' (adjective) from a primary source that refers to a British ship in 1649. The same 1649 quote attests the use of 'rate' in the nautical sense III.12.b.:

> Any of various classes into which vessels are divided, according (variously, at different times) to the seniority of the captain, the number of guns carried (cf. quot. 1769), complement of crew, or size. Now *hist.*
>    <sub>Often preceded by an ordinal numeral: cf. first rate *n.* 1a, second-rate *adj.*, etc.</sub>

No earlier attestation is given for 'first rate', 'second rate', etc.

*OED* is, however, somewhat constrained by its editorial policy regarding the types of sources acceptable; also, the *OED* selection of attesting quotes is constrained by the necessity of brevity as well as the *OED* focus on *lexical* rather than *general* historicity.

Thus, with regard to lexical historicity, [secondary source attestation](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=msu.31293010903106;view=1up;seq=304) of the nautical origin of 'third-rate' is available at least as early as February of 1638, in the [*Calendar of State Papers, Domestic Series, of the Reign of Charles I, 1637-1638*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=msu.31293010903106;view=1up;seq=7), which was edited and published in 1869:

> The Convertive, formerly of the *second rate*, is of late fallen down to the *third rate*, and has no more allowance of cordage than ships of the *third rate*.

The rating system "appears for the first time...in 1626", and did not, at the time, "mark any distinction in the force or construction of the ships", at least according to the source cited and excerpted by Wikipedia, W.H. Davenport Adams' 1885 [*England on the Sea; or, The Story of the British Navy, Its Decisive Battles and Great Commanders*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433008487245;view=1up;seq=146). Adams also mentioned the 1626 origin of the rating system in his 1863 [*Famous Ships of the British Navy*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=loc.ark:/13960/t0cv5qb78;view=1up;seq=23).

Answer (score 3):

**rate**  [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/rate)

> First-rate, second-rate, etc. are **1640.** From British Navy division
>   of ships into six classes based on size and strength.

and of **third**:  [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/third)

> Third-rate "of poor quality" is from 1814, ultimately from
>   classification of ships (1640s)

Evidence to suggest yes, related to the Br Navy. 3rd rate meaning 3 decks of cannon.

[image: 1st, 2nd, and 3rd class ships] 1728

[wiki file](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Warship_diagram_orig.jpg) and earlier:  Henry Grace à Dieu  1514  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Grace_%C3%A0_Dieu)

> Henry Grace à Dieu was one of the first vessels to feature gunports
>   and had twenty of the new heavy bronze cannon, allowing for a
>   broadside.

[image: Great Henry]

Comment: I saw that picture,  could  you find the date it was printed?

Comment: Is there a way to view a higher quality version of that image?  I can't read the text (including when clicking the link)

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime - try this link: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rating_system_of_the_Royal_Navy#/media/File%3AWarship_diagram_orig.jpg

Comment: 1728 - added ref to orig .jpg.

Comment: Is there any justification for everyone not agreeing with this? I wonder what this phenomenon is called. I see it all the time in online forums. Good find by the way.

Comment: @user070221 Agreeing with what is an excellent answer.

Comment: @user070221 I am wondering how I can be clearer.  I am talking about the fact that all those reading this have failed to give it upvotes; have failed to ***agree with*** it by upvoting...

Comment: @user070221  Of course, upvotes do not mean disagree. It means they ***agree***.  Sometimes it just ends up being impossible to try and be understood online. For the record, I am praising **lbf's*** answer. I provided no answer at all.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime - don’t want to sound too demanding, and I do think the finding is good. But unluckily that doesn’t solve the issue you pose...we need a picture or other written source that  dates before 1656, if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Citation from The Compact Edition of the OED (1971) under third-rate.

1649, Cromwell Let. 4 Nov. in Carlyle. The Garland, one of your third-rate ships, coming happily into Waterford Bay.